# How to deal with ß, ö, ä, ü etc. in an sql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a .csv file in German language(so with characters ä,ö,ü,ß) and I upload it to an sql server;
If I go to phpmyadmin and look at the table, these letters are shown correctly as ä,ö,ü,ß;
However when I get an entry from the table with such a letter it doesn't work anymore and these letters are just shown with a questionmark;
The script to upload and download is standard, so I use fopen to open the csv and then fill later the database with the value;
Also to get it from the database is standard, namely:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo $row['name']);
}
```

I guess it's a problem of the character encoding, however I don't know how to solve it; Anyone an idea?

I already tried to use:

```
$name[$i]= str_ireplace ( 'ß' , '&szlig;' , $name[$i] );
```

before uploading it to the database(the ß code in html) but however, the ß will not be overwritten and are still written as ß in the sql database if I upload it and look in phpmyadmin
If I use the command:

```
$name[$i]= str_ireplace ( 'a' , '&szlig;' , $name[$i] );
```

as an example, it works and all a are replace by ß and will be also displayed as ß in phpmyadmin;
But with ß it doesn't work; Anyone have some idea? :) Thank you very much!! :)

I don't know how to include the:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in my script so I did it with:

echo '';

Is that correct? But it didn't work unfortunately; However I tried this:

```
$test = utf8_encode ( $row['name'] );
echo $test;
```

and it worked; But if I get other columns having that special letters I need to write all the time:

```
 $test1 = utf8_encode ( $row['name1'] );
 $test2 = utf8_encode ( $row['name2'] );
```

etc. Is there a possibility to set it permanently and not just for one thing?

Comment: You are likely not setting a character set in your HTML and the default one doesn't include those characters.

Comment: Further to Jonathan's response, I think this is what you are looking for - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: yes, if you wanted to convert the characters to HTML entities like you are requesting, you would probably use `htmlentties` with a character set that includes those characters (assuming UTF-8). I believe though that this is not what you really need though as it was just what you figured your best solution would be. Really, you should be able to specify the character set in html (meta tag I believe, been a while) and the characters will display.

Answer (score 0):

3 steps:

1. can you print the csv when read, and see the special characters?
2. can you manually insert a special character directly from phpmyadmin to the database?
3. If both above answers are yes, my bet is $conn->set_charset("utf8"); if you worked with a connection object named $conn. A charset has to be set at the database connection as well

Edit: on second though this is probably not it, but i leave it as it is a common error with database and special characters, and worth a shot

Comment: I will check, give me some time.. :)

Comment: With already echo the name from the csv without uploading it to the database it still doesn't work; There is displayed an � just like with uploading it to the database and then get it from there and echo it...

Comment: Also, before the upload to the database you cant see the character, after retrieving you cannot see the character, but while on database from phpmyadmin you can see the character. Are all three things i just said correct?

Comment: 100% correct; And I have no idea if the php file is utf8 encoded? And id I don't know it probably means no then... :D

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
try printing this at the top of your page (it is html)